# Linux drawing too much power

Tags: dual-boot, power-management, asus, battery

I have a Asus FX505DY laptop with AMD Ryzen 5 3550H and Radeon RX560X. I recently dual booted Ubuntu and found out that I am getting very less battery life as compared to Windows(Ubuntu: 4-5 hrs, Windows: 9-10 hrs). I used *powerstat* and this is what I got:

[image: PowerStat Output]

This shows the Average Power Consumption as 15 Watts and according to the it should be around 5-7 for any normal laptop. What is happening here? How do I find out what is causing linux to use this much power?

Answer (score 0):

The cause is the driver support on Linux: less optimized drivers are the culprit.

I'd advise you to [install TLP](https://itsfoss.com/reduce-overheating-laptops-linux/): it's great for managing power and  its out-of-the-box settings are good to go.